# Filtering two json arrays with properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have to filter first array if the same object is present in second array using type script/ javascript

here is my arrays

```
var students = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},
{id: 2, name : 'SSa'},
{id: 3, name : 'SSb'},
{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},
{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}];

var emp = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},
{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},
{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}];
```

Output should be

```
var finalarr = [{id: 2, name : 'SSa'},
{id: 3, name : 'SSb'}]
```

i have tried below but produces wrong ouputs

```
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < emp.length; j++) {
    if (students[i].id != emp[j].id) {
    finalarr.push(students[i]);
    }
}
}
console.log(finalarr);
```

// below is my actual application code

```
this.appointmentTypes.filter((data, index) => this.typesData.includes(this.typesData[index].appointmentType.id))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects are references to memory locations - they'll never `===` each other unless they reference the same memory location, so `includes` won't work. Iterate over the whole array and test the names and IDs instead:

```js
var students=[{id:1,name:'SSS'},{id:2,name:'SSa'},{id:3,name:'SSb'},{id:4,name:'SSc'},{id:5,name:'SSd'}]
var emp=[{id:1,name:'SSS'},{id:4,name:'SSc'},{id:5,name:'SSd'}]

const finalArr = students.filter(({ id, name }) =>
  !emp.some(exclude => exclude.id === id && exclude.name === name)
);
console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: your answer is working for example array but it is retruning empty array for my original code please see below code which i have tried                                             let finalarr = this.appointmentTypes.filter((data) =>  {
            !this.typesData.some(item => item.appointmentType.id == data.id)
        })
        console.log (finalarr);

Comment: Please post your actual input in your question, that way the problem is reproducible.

Comment: i have provided a example it is very similar to my question, anyway thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

Your imperative attempt w/ loops fails because you push to final array when finding the first item with a different id.

It should be like

```js
var students = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},
{id: 2, name : 'SSa'},
{id: 3, name : 'SSb'},
{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},
{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}];

var emp = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},
{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},
{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}];

var finalarr = []

for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    let found = false // flag
    
    for (let j = 0; j < emp.length && !found; j++) {
      found = students[i].id === emp[j].id
    }
    
    if (!found) finalarr.push(students[i])
}

console.log(finalarr)
```

But a better option would be to create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of ids from the second array. `new Set(emp.map(item => item.id))` And the simply filter out all elements of the first array which ids are in the set using `filter(item => !set.has(item.id))`

```js
var students = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},
{id: 2, name : 'SSa'},
{id: 3, name : 'SSb'},
{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},
{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}];

var emp = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},
{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},
{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}];

console.log(
  students.filter(
    (set => item => !set.has(item.id))(new Set(emp.map(item => item.id)))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) tend to be great for solving filtration problems.

See below for more info

```js
// Input.
const students = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},{id: 2, name : 'SSa'},{id: 3, name : 'SSb'},{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}]
const emp = [{id: 1, name : 'SSS'},{id: 4, name : 'SSc'},{id: 5, name : 'SSd'}]

// Filter.
const filter = (A, B) => {
  const set = new Set(B.map(JSON.stringify))
  return A.filter(x => !set.has(JSON.stringify(x)))
}

// Output.
const output = filter(students, emp)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```